# Multiple maximal cyclic subgroups of a symmetry group

Tags: symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

If a symmetry group T has a maximal cyclic subgroup Cn because of a projection I1, then it means it will have a rotational symmetry order of n.

If we have another projection (of the same object) with rotational symmetry order of m. Does it mean that Cm is a maximal cyclic subgroup of the symmetry group?

Comment: I'm not sure about the meaning of "projection" here. Anyway, it is certainly possible that the symmetry group of an object has maximal cyclic subgroups of different cardinalities. For example the symmetry rotations of a cube have maximal cyclic subgroups of orders 4,2 and 3.

Comment: Download [this pdf-file](http://users.utu.fi/lahtonen/Ryhmateoria/Luento2701.pdf) from the slides for my on-going course on Group Theory. See the slides Esimerkki 4A.3, 4A.4 and 4A5. Depending on the capabilities of your browser, the animations may or may not work in the browser (they don't work in mine).